# Java preventing other network connections

Tags: java

I have a java application that does two things with an internet connection.  The first is a simple port 80 connect to send some data:

```
try {

        url = new URL(req);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(tOut);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        conn.setReadTimeout(urlTimeout);

        // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Line = Line + inputLine ;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();        
    }
```

The second is a ssh connection that looks for information coming from the server. The connection part is:

```
        con = SshConnector.createInstance();
        transport = new SocketTransport(hostname, port);
                    try {
                        ssh = con.connect(transport, username);
                    } catch (Exception es) {

                    }

        PasswordAuthentication pwd = new PasswordAuthentication();

        do {
            pwd.setPassword("password");
        } while (ssh.authenticate(pwd) != SshAuthentication.COMPLETE
                && ssh.isConnected());
```

Then I loop looking for input from the server.

I have one user that is on a Verizon Jetpack.  When my application is running the application runs slow, he cannot connect his VPN to his office, do a browser speed test, etc.  Close my application and the VPN and browser works fine.

I do not have that problem and many others running my application are fine.  Is there something I am overlooking or can change to keep from apparently shutting down his jetpack?

Tnx

Comment: Remove the `setPassword()/authenticate()` loop. If the password is wrong, it's wrong, and no amount of looping is going to change that. Similarly there may be something wrong with your 'loop looking for input from the server'.

Comment: Is there a better way to read input.  A lot of examples loop and get a character, but I was losing characters at time that way.  Using the buffered input has been rock solid.